# Are there autoimmune disorders caused or mediated only by T cells?

Tags: immunology, pathology, immune-system, autoimmune, immunoglobin

I have frequently read that 'most' or 'the vast majority' of autoimmune disorders involving the adaptive immune system are caused by autoantibodies.

These comments imply that there are known disorders involving only rogue T- cells.

Does anyone know of specific examples?  Is there a list somewhere?

Comment: Can you provide a link for where you heard that from please?

Comment: There are several primarily T-cell driven autoimmune diseases like Rheumatoid arthritis, Type 1 diabetes, Inflammatory bowel disease, Multiple sclerosis [PMID: 29123529, 32457742].